# How did trans-dimensional beings appear in Xindi council?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

The main goal of trans-dimensional beings was to make our dimension habitual to them. But, it seemed like the goal was meaningless when they could always exist in our dimension without glitch.

When Enterprise was trying to destroy Sphere 41, they appeared on the ship to malfunction the Enterprise. Trip argued that their existence here was impossible. But, Phlox told that the space was altered (by increased spatial anomalies around sphere 41) enough that they could exist. This seems reasonable, but how did they appear in unaltered dimension at Xindi council?

Comment: Holograms? (Don't remember for certain)

Comment: @Izkata Inter-dimensional holographic communication? Well, there wasn't any receiver on Xindi side. And, she was moving. One possibility: She was broadcasting her tele-presence in our dimension... :)

Comment: But, I am looking for canonical answer..

Comment: We can exist deep under water and in the vacuum of space, but it doesn't mean they are habitable for human life.  They just require expenditure of sufficient effort.  While individual trans-dimensional beings would be able to exist in our reality without the altered space they would not be able to move in en-mass

Comment: @TysonoftheNorthwest In this case, no.  There was one of the Sphere Builders that the Enterprise had "rescued" from a pod inside an anomaly.  He literally fell apart because they could not survive in our space.

Answer (score 5):

The Sphere Builders were not only trans-dimensional beings but also possessed [limited temporal technology](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Sphere_Builder) (although this appeared to be limited to looking forward to possible futures) and were involved in the [temporal cold war](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Temporal_Cold_War).

Several races have demonstrated advanced holographic technology, the [Xyrillians](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Xyrillian) encountered in 2151 and the "Think Tank" [Isomorphic projection](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Isomorphic_projection) encountered in 2375.

It's therefore likely that the Sphere Builders had either:

1. Holographic technology that was so good they appeared to "be there" without actually being in our in-hospitable dimension.
2. Life-support technology that allowed them to exist in our dimension for a short period of time.

Comment: I think there is an episode where she 'flickers' which does suggest a projection, i'd have to re-watch to find the episode though but that leans toward hologram too

Answer (score 0):

It would have had to have been holographic technology because she would have contacted the council way before sending out the test subject in the expanse. So to have survived, she would have had to alter space. What I don't get is how she would have built the identical spheres without even entering our side.